# Compass on 3GS is Different than on 4

Tags: iphone, compass-geolocation

I have a EMF meter app, similar to the teslameter source code given by apple.  the app works perfectly on the 3gs reading the numbers fine but on and iphone 4 it does not work at all.  Is there some major difference in the compass hardware?

The app is based on the magnetic readings from the compass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any relevant hardware differences.
The iPhone 4 also has a gyroscope, but it shouldn't alter magnetometer data.

Which behavior do you have? Any data at all?

Comment: Ok, yeah I thought it was just the compass, but I noticed in the apple source code version that the app reacts to motion as well.